# Unable to create RuntimeManager in jbpm java

Tags: java, jbpm, kie

I am trying to create RuntimeManager Using PerProcessInstanceRuntimeManager

```
ReleaseId releaseId = new ReleaseIdImpl("com.myorg.app.bpm", "myproject", "1.0");
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.jbpm.domain");
RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder builder = RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.Factory.get().newDefaultBuilder(releaseId).entityManagerFactory(emf).userGroupCallback(new CustomUserCallBack());
RuntimeManager runtimeManager = RuntimeManagerFactory.Factory.get().newPerProcessInstanceRuntimeManager(builder.get(), "com.sample:example:1.0");
```

Error Which i got is :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Named query not found:
>   FindKSessionToInit
>         at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:636)
>         at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.mapper.JPAMapper.findKSessionToInit(JPAMapper.java:205)
>         at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.PerProcessInstanceRuntimeManager.init(PerProcessInstanceRuntimeManager.java:322)
>         at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.newPerProcessInstanceRuntimeManager(RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.java:97)

Please suggest some ideas to overcome this

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using your own persistence.xml?  This query is defined in the ContextMappingInfo class:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-runtime-manager/src/main/java/org/jbpm/runtime/manager/impl/jpa/ContextMappingInfo.java#L48

This class should be in your persistence.xml:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-installer/db/jbpm-persistence-JPA2.xml#L55